# add a username field to login form with accounts-entry package

Tags: meteor

i installed the account-entry package.
in the default configuration this package request an Email for authentication. 
How can i add a username field to the signIn/logIn from that will persists in DB.

Answer (score 0):

All i nedded to do is change the passwordSignupFields attribute to 'USERNAME_AND_EMAIL' in the package. (/packages/accounts-entry/client/entry.coffee)

Answer (score 0):

No need to fiddle with "/packages/accounts-entry/client/entry.coffee". Just do something like:

```
AccountsEntry.config({
   passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_EMAIL'
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i tried it and it Throws "Cannot read property 'config' of undefined" . any way I don't think the ability to change the authentication theme should be given to the client.

Comment: Sorry, thought you used the accounts-ui package. Updated my answer